# How to check that the email Id on the person account selected on a case is null or not

Tags: apex, trigger, person-accounts

I want to check in my trigger on a case whether the email Id of the person account for the case is an null or not. I have a lookup to contact(person account) on the case page.
How to achieve this.

```
for (case caseObj : trigger.new){
 ......
}
```

in this for loop I tried

```
caseObj.account.personal email == null;
caseObj.contact.email == null;
caseObj.ContactEmail == null;
```

but it didn't work out can anyone help.

Comment: Even I faced similar issue.
Ultimately I had to post a query for that particular contact.

Keep us posted if you find anything regarding this.

Comment: Posting a query was the possible solution. But solution by @Marty C. also holds value and is worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your null tests fail is that in a Trigger on Case, the lookup objects are not in scope. To wit:

```
for (Case caseobj : Trigger.new)
    caseObj.contact.email == null;
```

Trigger.new will have in scope the fields on Case, but not the parent fields on account or contact. You need to query for these:

```
Map<ID,Case> caseIdToCaseWithParentMap = new Map<ID,Case>(
        [select id, contact.email from Case in :Trigger.new]);

for (Case caseobj: Trigger.new)
    if (caseIdToCaseWithParentMap.get(caseObj.id).contact.email == null) // do something
```

Comment: Thanks crop1645. I implemented this approach to solve my problem as this was the most suitable one.

Comment: I have one Question though. I do have a standard field 'Contact Email' on the case, which gets populated once I select the contact and save the case. Can't I use this field to check if contact has email or not.

Comment: Only standard fields documented here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/index.htm will be available. With Cases, SFDC makes available some convenience fields in the UI which aren't actually on the object that a trigger references.  'Contact Email' is not one of the actual fields in the Case SObject and hence is not available to the trigger.new context

Answer (score 1):

Bhoopesh, one way you can access the related Contact record's Email value is to create a Formula (Text) field on the Case object called **Contact Email** (`ContactEmail__c`). The formula just needs to be: `Contact.Email`

Once you have this formula field, you'll be able to use this formula field to determine whether the Contact record has a blank Email, as demonstrated in the following example.

```
trigger RequireContactEmail on Case (before insert) {
    for (Case eachCase : Trigger.new) {
        System.assert(eachCase.ContactEmail__c != null,
            'The Contact must have an Email value');
    }
}
```

See the screenshot below for the definition of the formula field, paying special attention to the setting to **treat blank fields as blanks**.

[image]

Comment: But sadly I can't create a new formula field due to some restrictions from business. So I fetched it from the system using SOQL query just as @crop1645 mentioned.

Comment: I have one Question though. I do have a standard field 'Contact Email' on the case, which gets populated once I select the contact and save the case. Can't I use this field to check if contact has email or not.

Comment: The standard Contact Email field is not available for use in formula fields or Apex at the current time.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect the problem you're having is that you're testing for "null". An email field is a special case of a text field. You need to be testing for `isEmpty() == false`. Your code should look more like this:

```
Boolean emlResult = caseObj.contact.email.isEmpty();
if(emlResult == true){

 // perform operation

}else{

// report no email address and do something else

}
```